# Анимация барабана игрового автомата

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

Знакомлюсь с анимацией в android, по гайдам научился "Восхождение солнца"
Пытаюсь разобраться как делаются более сложные анимации, например барабан. Получается барабан состоит из каких-то элементов, которые вращаются в одну сторону, но когда элементы уходят за край, получается что элемент нужно переместить на другой край и продолжать крутить.

Где об этом вообще можно почитать?
Полагаю для всех элементов нужно разом запустить несколько анимаций прокрутки с разным стартом(или их можно как-то объединить?) Можно ли сделать xml с входящими параметрами, вроде откуда, докуда и сколько раз крутить?

"Восхождение солнца"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.5" />

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="80%p"
        android:toYDelta="10%p" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.3"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

В главном активити для вызова анимации прописываю

```
// Анимация для восхода солнца
Animation sunRiseAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.sun_rise);
// Подключаем анимацию к нужному View
sunImageView.startAnimation(sunRiseAnimation);
```